# Looking for a free log file reader

Tags: logging

I am looking for a free text log reader that can read the logs (trace logs for example) live, as they get written to. Pause and Resume functions would be nice too.

I should clarify - the tool needs to run on Windows.

Comment: Technology? Programming Language?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113121/best-tail-log-file-visualization-freeware-tool ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I use [baretail](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/), free version available

Comment: this is what I needed, lightweight text file monitoring. Thanks, devio!

Comment: does it have search functionality?

Answer (score 4):

In Windows, NotePad++ does the trick (supports live text file monitoring)...

Comment: Doesn't work for large log files.

Answer (score 3):

tail -f path-to-logfile

pause: ctrl-z
resume: fg

works in unix/linux shells or cygwin

Alternatively, use 'less' command (unix/cygwin). Press 'F' (shift+F) while running it, and 'less' will work as 'tail' command ... will show you tail of your log file. Pause: 'ctrl-C', resume: press 'F' again.